# How to remove footer details in org-mode html export?

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode

When exporting an org-mode file into html with content as simple as "Hello World!", the exported .html file contains this in the footer:

```
Date: 2012-11-13 16:06:19 CET

Author: <name>

Org version 7.8.11 with Emacs version 24
Validate XHTML 1.0
```

Is there a way to get rid of this information and just be presented with a simple "Hello World!" in the resulting .html?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
(setq org-export-html-postamble nil)
```

You can also customize the footer by modifying a variable `org-export-html-postamble-format`

Comment: Is there a way to put this in the `#+` per-file options?

Comment: @Trevor Alexander I don't thin so.

Comment: The list [13.1.5 Options for the exporters](http://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing-options.html)

Comment: Putting `(setq org-export-html-postamble nil)` in init.el and rebooting Emacs then works for me.

Comment: This is now `(setq org-html-postamble nil)`.

Answer (score 54):

You can also use, inside your org file, the below option:

```
#+OPTIONS: html-postamble:nil
```

To view most of existing html export options, type `C-c C-e # html RET` in org buffer and it  will insert the template of HTML options.

2014-01-21 : There is another way to answer the initial question, not yet described in any other answer. File local variable org-html-postamble set to nil. This can be done with <kbd>M-x</kbd> add-file-local-variable <kbd>RET</kbd> org-html-postamble <kbd>RET</kbd> nil <kbd>RET</kbd>. This will add lines like the following to the end of file.

```
# Local Variables:
# org-html-postamble: nil
# End:
```

Comment: The second method somehow fails. And adding `(setq org-html-postamble nil)` to init.el does not work, either. Any idea?

Comment: @user69818 The second method, aka "file local variable", means that the variable must be set in the *org* file. Not in the init.el file.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to remove it on a per-file basis is

```
#+style: <style>#postamble { display:none; }</style>
```

Comment: I just did something similar, but used a `#+begin_html/end_html` block after my Org file's preamble (e.g. `#+options`) and before the first heading. Inside the html blocks I have the standard `<style> css attributes </style>` bit, like shown above. I think it's not working for you, @jbyler , possibly because either 1) the above is only for pointing to a `.css` file (not raw code), or 2) due to the updated [Org 8.0 syntax](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-8.0.html#sec-8-3) (`#+style` is now `#+html_head`).

Answer (score 4):

I was unable to get the answer by thdox to work. To turn off postamble export on a per-file basis, I inserted

```
#+BIND: org-export-html-postamble nil
```

at the top of my file. From the org-mode manual:

> If org-export-allow-bind-keywords is non-nil, Emacs variables can become buffer-local during export by using the BIND keyword. Its syntax is ‘#+BIND: variable value’. This is particularly useful for in-buffer settings that cannot be changed using specific keywords.

This should therefore work for turning off any export options on a per-file basis.

Comment: Note that `org-export-allow-bind-keywords` is nil by default, and the `#+BIND` will be silently ignored in that case.  While you can change that value in your emacs global settings, that's a security risk.  You can narrow the scope of the security risk somewhat by using a mode line: `# -*- org-export-allow-bind-keywords: t; -*-` although this has the downside that you will be prompted to allow the unsafe variable every time you open the file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm exporting to LaTeX, and I was getting the emacs version and org-mode version emitted at the end of the doc.  Turns out that's the "CREATOR" var, so to disable exporting that:

```
#+OPTIONS: creator:nil
```

worked for me.  You can do the same with `author` and `date` and other fields.

Comment: Worked for HTML as well.